Как обеспечить относительный путь к БД SQLite?
я пробовал запросом insert вставить данные к таблицам через абсолютный путь к БД и все работает, а вот через относительный не выходит, сделал автоопределение каталога тип где он находится через Path.Combine но все равно не вышло.
Вот мой код:
public class ElGamalParametersExporter
{
private string connectionString;

public ElGamalParametersExporter(string dbFileName)
{
    string relativePathToDB = Path.Combine("database", dbFileName);
    string absolutePathToDB = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, relativePathToDB);
    connectionString = $"Data Source={absolutePathToDB}";
}

public void ExportParameters(BigInteger p, BigInteger g, BigInteger x, BigInteger y)
{
    try
    {
        using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            // Вставляем параметры p и g в таблицу ElGamalParameters
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ElGamalParameters (P, G) VALUES (@p, @g)";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", p.ToString());
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g", g.ToString());
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            // Вставляем открытый ключ y в таблицу ElGamalPublicKey
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ElGamalPublicKey (PublicKey) VALUES (@y)";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@y", y.ToString());
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            // Вставляем закрытый ключ x в таблицу ElGamalPrivateKey
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ElGamalPrivateKey (PrivateKey) VALUES (@x)";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", x.ToString());
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(null,"Ошибка при экспорте параметров и ключей в базу данных: " + ex.Message,);
    }
}

и ее реализация в кнопке
private void Gen_param_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Генерация ключей ElGamal
Tuple<ElGamalParameters, BigInteger, BigInteger> keys = ElGamalKeyGenerator.GenerateElGamalKeys();

// Получение параметров и ключей
BigInteger p = keys.Item1.P;
BigInteger g = keys.Item1.G;
BigInteger x = keys.Item2;
BigInteger y = keys.Item3;

// Вывод значений в MetroTextBox элементы
textBoxP.Text = p.ToString();
textBoxG.Text = g.ToString();
textBoxPrivateKey.Text = x.ToString();
textBoxPublicKey.Text = y.ToString();

string absolutePathToDB = @".\database\Keys.db";
ElGamalParametersExporter exporter = new ElGamalParametersExporter(absolutePathToDB);
exporter.ExportParameters(p, g, x, y);
}

Вот полный путь к БД:
D:\Учеба\ИТИ магис\2 курс 2 сем\Диссертация\проект\Programs\EL_Gamal\EL_Gamal\database\Keys.db
и поставил свойство копировать в выходной каталог с 0 на 1
Подскажите как задать относительный путь чтоб работал запрос Insert, если на абсолютном он работает нормально.

название_переменной_бд =
  new DB(
    Path.Combine(
      Environment.GetFolderPath(
        Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData
      ), "Имя_файла_бд"
    )
  );


Не забудьте по System.IO

ну все понятно кроме начала строки когда объявляем ее как тип а не как переменную

а он почему то на диск C ссылается

хотя такого пути не существует я уже проверил
